# Video Analytics for HLS/Live stream

Tags: video, google-analytics, analytics, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

This may not be a purely technical question, but not sure the best place to put it.

So we have a live streaming website (think MTV). We use HTTP Live Streaming to deliver the content. So the stream consists of a bunch of videos. We would like to get analytics on this. Since it's not separate videos that are being watched, but all one stream, what is the best way to collect analytics on this?

Things like:
- what video in the stream is a user leaving/stopping etc.
- how long in the video currently in the stream do they watch before leaving/stopping

Stuff like that. We currently use jwplayer, but it does not look like their analytics system supports this. Is there anything that does? Would we have to use google analytics and make custom calls?

Any thoughts would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The JW Player's Analytics, as well as our Google Analytics integration, will be able to capture the streams played, but that would be it, as the % complete, stopped, etc, wouldn't be tracked, as the streams are live.

Comment: This is what jwplayer told me: "With our current analytics, you will be able to see the average time viewed for the m3u8 itself. The files contained within will not be separate in our analytics.". So i'd know that the live-stream.m3u8 is playing and analytics on that. But not what videos we have embedded in the stream?

Comment: Yes, you would be able to see the overall manifest, but not the ones inside if that makes sense.